# Bulkupdate change language for source folder

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I am running power shell script to bind treelist data in both language english & french.even if i change language am getting only English content in french .please review my script and let me know what am missing?

```
       #Upload the file on the Server in temporary folder
       #It will create the folder if it is not found
         $TargetLanguage = "fr-CA"
         $Language = "en"

      $dataFolder = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::DataFolder
      $tempFolder = $dataFolder + "\temp\upload"
      $filePath = Receive-File -Path $tempFolder -overwrite
      $templatePath = "Chartwell/Project/Website/Page Template/Property" 

     $contentPath = "master:/content/Web3/Content Shared Folder/Property"

     if($filePath -eq "cancel"){
      exit
     }

       #Property Section
      $AllProperties = Get-ChildItem -Path 
          "master://sitecore/content/Web3/Content Shared Folder/Property 
           Page" -Recurse

     #Dining Section            
      $AllDining = Get-ChildItem -Path 
    "master://sitecore/content/Web3/Content Shared Folder/Dining Service" - 
     Recurse



        $resultSet =  Import-Csv $filePath

      $rowsCount = ( $resultSet | Measure-Object ).Count;

if($rowsCount -le 0){
    Remove-Item $filePath
    exit
}

  Write-Log "Bulk Update Started!";
        New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {
     foreach ( $row in $resultSet ) {

    $PropertyID = $row."PropertyID";    #Here
    $Property = $AllProperties  | Where-Object { $_."Legacy ID" -eq 
         $PropertyID };

        if ($Property){

        $DiningDataID = $row."DiningDataID";
        $DiningData = $AllDining   | Where-Object { $_."Legacy ID" -eq 
            $DiningDataID };

        $ID = $Property."Dining Service"
        if($ID -eq '')
        {
            $ID = $DiningData.id
        }
        else
        {               
            $ID = $ID + "|" +$DiningData.id
        }           

        $Property.Editing.BeginEdit();
        $Property["Dining Service"] = $ID;  #Here
                   #FrenchSection
        $langAdd = Add-ItemLanguage -Item $Property -Language $Language -TargetLanguage $TargetLanguage -IfExist Skip;
                 Write-Log $Property.id 
        $Property.Editing.EndEdit();
                    $ItemPath = $ContentPath + "\" + $Property 
        $NewcurrentItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Id $Property.id -Language $TargetLanguage
        $NewcurrentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        $NewcurrentItem["Dining Service"] = $ID; 

        $NewcurrentItem.Editing.EndEdit();

    }
    else {
        $logThis =  "Couldn't find Property with ID: " + $PropertyID + " Property Item: " + $Property;
        $logThis;
        Write-Log $logThis;
    }
}
}
$logInfo = "Bulk Update is Completed!";
$logInfo
Write-Log $logInfo

    Remove-Item $filePath
```

how to change language of the         $AllDining ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `Language` parameter to your `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet call

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Language "ja-JP"
```

in this case, `ja-JP` is a language code. Use the want that you need.

If you need the same item but in every language use `*`

```
Get-ChildItem . -Language "*"
```

Comment: how to switch it ?incase of two language am i need to write script twice for english one script and french another script

Comment: You can use variable that you have on the top. `Get-ChildItem . -Language "$TargetLanguage"`

Comment: i changed but now am having english data twice in french version.

Comment: could you please check my updated script am very new to powershell script

Comment: please check this syntax                 $AllDiningFR = Get-ChildItem -Path "master://sitecore/content/Web3/Content Shared Folder/Dining Service" -Language $TargetLanguage

Comment: @sitecore-u9 please experiment by yourself. You will not learn PowerShell if people will write code for you. Split code into parts and check step by step where is the problem. You can debug your code as well if your script cannot be split into parts.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rhPWVKcreI